# In UWP Javascript, is there any way to detect that a secondary window has closed?

Tags: javascript, uwp

Using the WinJS [projection sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection) I've implemented some code to open up a second window

```
window.view = window.open(url, null, "msHideView=no");
```

Now what I want to do is set up a callback for when `window.view` is closed, eg by pressing the X button in the top right. Something like `view.on('close', function(){}` or `view.addEventListener()`. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [SystemNavigationManagerPreview.CloseRequested Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview.systemnavigationmanagerpreview.closerequested) in [Windows.UI.Core.Preview Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.preview). This event occurs when the user invokes the system button for close (the 'x' button in the corner of the app's title bar).

To make this API work successfully, you need to add a restricted capability `confirmAppClose` in 'package.appxmanifest' file.

```
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
     IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

```
<Capabilities>
   <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>
</Capabilities>
```

```
/*secondaryView.js*/
var Preview = Windows.UI.Core.Preview;
```

```
Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.getForCurrentView().addEventListener("closerequested", onCloseRequested);

function onCloseRequested(eventArgs) {
    /*your code*/
}
```

Comment: I understand where to put the `<Capabilities>...` xml, but not the `xmlns:rescap`. That doesn't even look like valid xml to me.

Comment: Implemented `window.opener.postMessage()` inside secondaryView.js to tell the opening file when the second view is closed.